# Writing in a .txt file with specified directory on Android

Tags: android, file, android-emulator

I am working on a small application on Android.
My app is only to be used on the emulator. I would like to be able to write some outputs in a .txt file with a chosen directory (for example write in a file which will be in my computer's desktop)

this is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText search_app = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_app); 
                String App = search_app.getText().toString();

                PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                PackageInfo packageInfo;


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ApkInfo.class);
                i.putExtra(NAME, App);
                startActivity(i);

                try {
                      OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myfilename.txt",0));
                      out.write(App);
                      out.close();
                    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });

    }
```

I can't find where is the file saved by default.
How can I specify where I would like to be saved on my computer ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Android is not a desktop os. It's not saving anything to the system it's running its emulator on.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is stored on your Android device in a specific location where it can be accessed only by your app, it is `/data/data/your_package_name`. If you are running on emulator the file is stored in emulator's space, not on your desktop. You need to use the [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) tool to pull it from there.

Here is the [explanation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) about internal storage.

Comment: Can you explain me how to use the adb tool to have access to the file ? Is that possible with the adb tool to read the file in the emulator's space and to rewrite the content in another file with another directory ?